# Fully Connected Graph to Lattice

Tags: graphs, np-hard, lattices, subgraphs

I am looking for algorithms (or at least something similar to the problem definition):

Given a fully-connected weighted graph $G$ with $n$ nodes, find a subset $S$ of edges that form a [square lattice graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph) (where each node, except for the ones at the edges, is connected to 4 other nodes) such that the sum of edge weights in $S$ is minimal.

I realize the problem might be NP-complete; if so, are there good approximation algorithms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is NP-Hard.

Consider the variant of the problem in which you need to delete the edges of a complete graph with $n$ vertices in order to obtain a $1 \times n$ lattice of minimum weight.
This variant is clearly NP-Hard. Indeed, you turn any (not necessarily complete) graph $G=(V, E)$  into a weighted complete graph $H$ by setting the weights of the edges in $E$ to $0$ and by adding all the missing edges with weight $1$. There is a $1 \times n$ lattice (i.e., simple path of length $n-1$) of weight $0$ in $H$ if and only if $G$ is Hamiltonian.

To show that finding a $N \times N$ lattice is also NP-Hard you can augment the graph $H$ by adding $n^2-n$ "dummy" vertices organized into a $(n-1) \times n$ lattice $L$ (so that $N=n^2$). The weights of all the edges in $L$ are set to $-1$. The weights of all the remaining edges are set to $0$.

Let $m_L$ be the number of edges in $L$.

If there is a Hamiltonian path $P$ in $G$ then you can find a lattice with weight $-m_L$: the first row is exactly the path $P$ while the rest of the graph is $L$.

If there is a lattice with weight at most $-m_L$ then it must contain $L$ as a sub-lattice. Therefore the $n$ vertices of $G$ must all be in the topmost/bottom row or in the leftmost/rightmost column and must contribute $0$ to the overall weight. This means that the path $P$ induced by that row/column contains only edges in $E$, i.e., $P$ is a Hamiltonian path of $G$.

If you don't like negative edge weights, you can scale all the weights up by an additive constant.
Moreover, by setting the weight of the edges in $V^2 \setminus E$ to some large value, you can create an arbitrarily large gap between the weights of "yes" and "no" instances, ruling out the existence of approximation algorithms (unless P=NP).

Comment: Yes, I am aware that the problem is NP-complete (as TSP can be reduced to it), but I was more curious if approximate algorithms may exist. Which is why I am not fully sure I understand what you meant by the last sentence: "Moreover, by setting the weight of the edges in V2∖E
 to some large value, you can create an arbitrarily large gap between the weights of "yes" and "no" instances, ruling out the existence of approximation algorithms (unless P=NP)."